# Filter HashMap using Java 8 lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am trying to keep all entries in the Map where the key is in the list of Strings. This is what I have:

```
List<String> outputKeys = Arrays.asList("key1", "key2", "key3");
foo = map.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .filter(p -> outputKeys.contains(p.getKey()))
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
```

There are compilation errors at p.getKey() and p.getValue():

```
Error:(151, 75) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getKey()
location: variable p of type java.lang.Object
```

Comment: How is `map` declared?

Comment: ... and how is `foo` declared?

Comment: `Map map;` and `Map<String, Object> foo = null;`

Comment: And what is the compilation error?

Comment: I think it needs to be `Map<String, Object> map;`,

Comment: @Paul You are right! thanks!

Comment: Here is my answer (I can't post it any more). If you use the raw type `Map` (rather than `Map<String, Object>`), **all** type information for `map` is ignored. Therefore the method `entrySet` is treated as if it returns a raw `Set`, not a `Set<Map.Entry<...>>`. This means (bizarrely) that the methods `getKey` and `getValue` cannot be resolved. If you declare `map` to be of type `Map<String, Object>` the problem disappears.